# React router not getting refreshed after routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have an app.js wherein i call Home.js via routing , Home.js consists of two other components called Service and List such that when Service is clicked it goes to List. I have another route wherein when i click any content in List , it should go to new component DisplayData but it is going to Home.js , and i have to manually refresh the page for the contents of DisplayData to be rendered .App.js

```
 App.js 
 <Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Link to="/services"><button className="btn btn-primary m-3">Services</button></Link>
    <Route path="/services" exact component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/service/:service_name/requests" exact component={DisplayData}/>
  </div>
  </Router>

 Home.js
 const Home = () => {
 return(
 <Router>
 <div className="main-wrapper">
  <div className="service-wrapper">
    <Service/>
  </div>
  <div className="list-wrapper">
    <Route path="/service/:service_name" exact component={List}/>
  </div>
 </div>
 </Router>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only have a single Router instance in your App. Also you should remove exact keyword from `/service` path and use `Switch with Route path reordering` otherwise the nested Routes within Home won't be re-rendered

**App.js**

```
 <Router>
  <div className="App">
    <Link to="/services"><button className="btn btn-primary m-3">Services</button></Link>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/service/:service_name/requests" exact component={DisplayData}/>
        <Route path="/services" component={Home}/>
    <Switch>
  </div>
</Router>
```

**Home.js**

```
 const Home = () => {
    return(
         <div className="main-wrapper">
          <div className="service-wrapper">
            <Route component={Service}/>
          </div>
          <div className="list-wrapper">
            <Route path="/service/:service_name" exact component={List}/>
          </div>
        </div>
     );
}
```

Comment: if i remove Router from Home.js the route is not happening , only the url is changed and goes to another page but no data in rendered , i need the data of List component to be rendered in the same page as Service, (Service on the left side and upon clicking , List on the right side ).

Comment: Did you make the other changes too that I mentioned in the answr

Comment: yes did , i made the changes first to app.js and then removed the Router from Home.js but the moment i do that , List component is not getting rendered

Comment: You removed the exact keyword too right from services path??

Comment: okay, so the logic to link to `List` component path is in Services in which case you should also render Services as a Route

Comment: if i do that , wont my service component disappear when List component appears ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190482/discussion-between-nishant-and-shubham-khatri).